# Group algebra of Lie group

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group over a field $K$, say $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Can we define the group algebra $KG$ of $G$? I assume that since $G$ is continuous, we might have to look at integrals, so a general element $a \in KG$ would look something like $\int_G \lambda_x x$. This is well-defined since $G$ is compact. Does something like this exist? If so, are there any interesting results/literature on them?

Comment: Integration over (locally) compact Lie groups is indeed well-defined. For more on how such integration is defined and used, look into [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I guess (in my now deleted comments) I wasn't thinking carefully about the definition of $KG$ and was a bit too cavalier with formal sums. So for instance, in $\Bbb C U(n)$ it is not the case that $(\operatorname{id}) + (-\operatorname{id}) = 0$. Is that the issue?

Comment: @Ben: yes. The group algebra is constructed to have the property that modules over it correspond to representations of the group, in full generality. So you can't assume any additive relations that only hold in a particular representation (for $U(n)$, the defining representation on $\mathbb{C}^n$), because these relations have no reason to hold in other representations. The group algebra is just formal sums of elements of the group and that's all; it has dimension the cardinality of the group, which again for a Lie group is usually uncountable.

Comment: @Qiaochu Thanks, I appreciate the correction and your motivation for the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can define the group algebra $K[G]$ as usual. Problem is a bit that the word group algebra is quite overloaded, and esp. when talking about topological groups or Lie groups you could also be talking about a lot of other things.

Other objects also called group algebra include:

- If $G$ is topological: $C(G)$ (continuous functions on $G$ w/ convolution), $\mathcal{M}(G)$ (regular signed/complex measures on $G$ w/ convolution)
- If $G$ is topological and locally compact: $L^1(G)$ (integrable functions w.r.t. some fixed Haar measure w/ convolution), $C_c(G)$ (compactly supported continuous functions), $\mathcal{M}_c(M)$ (compactly supported signed/complex measures)
- If $G$ is Lie: $C^\infty(G)$ and $C_c^\infty(G)$ (smooth (compactly supported) functions w/ convolution), $\mathcal{D}(G)$ and $\mathcal{D}_c(G)$ ((compactly supported) distributions w/ convolution)

and so on. Note that most of them don't have a 1 (exceptions: measures and distributions), and that in the case of $G$ finite they all reduce more or less to the group algebra that we know. Given a representation of $G$, you can also build a representation of most of these algebras (but you probably have to worry about finiteness of the integrals, so better stick to the compactly supported ones... Or to compact groups), which is where/how I first heard about those other group algebras: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_representation